# Query between two intervals of time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

In my app I have Clients and Professionals. A professional can set his availability of work, my Availability model has "start_time", "end_time", they are time without time zone.

So a client wants to hire a professional that is available at 20:00 to 22:00 for example.

How can I query that?

Comment: This question is hard to answer without knowing how your models exactly look like. Does a Professional have only one Availability? What happens when he is booked, is the Availability deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have two input values, and you want to make sure the time block they delineate fits inside a second block, delineated by the `start_time` and `end_time` attributes of your model. I would think this would be as simple as

```
Professional.joins(:availability).where('start_time <= :start AND end_time >= :end', :start => first_input, :end => second_input)
```

Depending on your model (multiple Availabilities per Professional, for instance) there might be some additional complexity, though.